# Difference between TableAdapter.Fillby() and TableAdapter.GetDataby()

Tags: c#, dataset

What are the differences between `FillBy()` and `GetDataBy()` methods in TableAdapters?

Comment: You could have just read the documentation - see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tthwx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). `TableAdapter.Fill` Populates the TableAdapter's associated data table with the results of the TableAdapter's SELECT command. `TableAdapter.GetData` Returns a new DataTable filled with data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FillBy` fills an already created `DataTable`, but `GetDataBy` creates a new `DataTable`. That's the only difference.